# Java: Does the amount of times you call Math.random() affect the outcome

Tags: java

I had to do homework to create a bingo game, so I created a method which returns an int array with 25 random numbers for each bingo card and 75 random numbers for gameplay, (the cards have to be 5x5 2d arrays populated with random numbers from 1 - 75 and for gameplay I need to be able to call from 1 - 75 in random order) I find that with 2 players the first one wins at least 80% of the times I tested it, although I would expect it to be closer to 50\50 at some times,
this is my method:

```
 public int[] pickAllNumbers(){
    boolean[] picks = new boolean[LARGEST_NUM + 1];
    int numbersLength;
    int[] numbers;
    if (this instanceof Card) {
        numbersLength = BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE;
    } else {
        numbersLength = LARGEST_NUM;
    }
    numbers = new int[numbersLength];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < numbersLength){
        int pick = (int)(Math.random() * LARGEST_NUM) +1;
        if(!picks[pick]){
            picks[pick] = true;
            numbers[i] = pick;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

LARGEST_NUM is 75, and BOARD_SIZE is 5;
when I call it from my Card class I use it to populate a 2d array for the card, and when I call it in my Main class I use it to create an array of 75 length to call each number for the game

Comment: Aside: there's no need to fill `picks` with `false`. It goes out of scope immediately after, so you just discard it anyway.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'll edit, I thought that would somehow affect the outcome...

Comment: I don't see a problem related to your question in the code, so its either somewhere else or @grian is right.

Comment: I assume @grian is right too, I didn't post the rest of the code as it will be to long, my question essentially is if Math.random called many times over affects the randomness, otherwise the problem is obviously with my code, or the insufficient amount of tests

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how many times you've ran this test, but over time and a lot(millions) of iterations it'll balance out to 50/50 or close enough. I'm assuming you haven't ran your test this much, and over a small amount of iterations it won't balance out to 50/50, as this is not how randomness works.

Comment: Thanks! I understood when you have 25 random numbers * 2 within 1 - 75, then a list of 75 random numbers should match up to either the same amount of times statistically quicker then millions of iterations,

Comment: @YehudaB It was more or less a rough estimate but yes